# passing file names to a script which takes multiple arguments which are modified names of the input file using xargs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, xargs

I have a script that accepts two files as parameters (`run_this file1 file2`). I have bunch of files that I select with

```
ls analysis-{A,B,C}*-[123][abc].csv
```

and for each of those I also need to pass the corresponding file that only differs in name by prefix: instead of `analysis`, it starts with `analysis_q`. I tried many options I know but `sed` seems to refuse cooperation with `xargs` (and I know of no other simple way)

one of the things I tried:

```
ls analysis-{A,B,C}*-[123][abc].csv | xargs --interactive -I '{}' run_this `$(echo {} | sed 's/analysis/analysis_q/g')` {}
```

I am hoping to produce

```
run_this analysis_q-A-1a.csv analysis-A-1a.csv
run_this analysis_q-A-1b.csv analysis-A-1b.csv
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a plain old loop.

```
for f1 in analysis-{A,B,C}*-[123][abc].csv; do
    f2=$(sed 's/analysis/analysis_q/g' <<<"$f1")
    run_this "$f1" "$f2"
done
```

For xargs, I would remove the prefix and use the variable part only.

```
printf "%s\n" analysis-{A,B,C}*-[123][abc].csv |
sed 's/^analysis-//' |
xargs --interactive -I {} run_this analysis-{} analysis_q-{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, using `sed` and `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\n' analysis-*.csv |
    sed -E 's/^(analysis)(.*)/\1_q\2 \1\2/' |
    xargs -n2 echo run_this
```

Remove `echo` when you are happy with the output.

###### Output

```
run_this analysis_q-A-1a.csv analysis-A-1a.csv
run_this analysis_q-A-1b.csv analysis-A-1b.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash can do search and replace on variable just fine, it is called *variable expansion* or *variable substitution*:

```bash
for f in analysis-{A,B,C}*-[123][abc].csv
do
    echo run_this "${f/analysis/analysis_q}" "$f"
done
```

Once this works for you, remove the `echo` and script will be run. The expression `${f/analysis/analysis_q}` takes the value of `$f`, replace *analysis* with *analysis_q*.

This method does not use `ls`, `sed`, or `xargs` at all. It is pure bash.